# Azure Logic app failing - unable to set variable

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

i have a azure logic app. in a condition it checks for four payment methods 'Cash' 'Cheque' 'Credit Card' 'Transfer'. then it set to a variable in a following step. if it is not a payment method from above four it shows an error saying '
InvalidTemplate. The 'start index' for function 'substring' must be equal to or greater than zero and must be less than '1' which is the length of the string.https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#substring' and then the logic app fails. its okay even the payment method is incorrect  the logic app should flow

Comment: Can you provide Flow design or code so that we can see where the problem for better understanding

Comment: So what do you want the outcome to be if it fails?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Here I initialized a blank variable and then done by using below design.

**`Design:`**

[image]

Then:

[image]

**`Used True False in Conditions:`**

[image]

**`Code View:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['get']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Condition": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_string_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "var",
                            "value": "Cash"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                    }
                },
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "equals": [
                                    "@outputs('Compose')",
                                    "Cheque"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "equals": [
                                    "@outputs('Compose')",
                                    "CreditCard"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "equals": [
                                    "@outputs('Compose')",
                                    "Transfer"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded",
                        "Failed"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "If"
            },
            "Condition_2": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_string_variable_2": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "var",
                            "value": "Cheque"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                    }
                },
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "equals": [
                                    "@outputs('Compose')",
                                    "Cash"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "equals": [
                                    "@outputs('Compose')",
                                    "CreditCard"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "equals": [
                                    "@outputs('Compose')",
                                    "Transfer"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded",
                        "Failed"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "If"
            },
            "Condition_3": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_string_variable_3": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "var",
                            "value": "CreditCard"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                    }
                },
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "equals": [
                                    "@outputs('Compose')",
                                    "Cheque"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "equals": [
                                    "@outputs('Compose')",
                                    "Cash"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "equals": [
                                    "@outputs('Compose')",
                                    "Transfer"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "If"
            },
            "Condition_4": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_string_variable_4": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "var",
                            "value": "Transfer"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                    }
                },
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "equals": [
                                    "@outputs('Compose')",
                                    "Cash"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "equals": [
                                    "@outputs('Compose')",
                                    "CreditCard"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "equals": [
                                    "@outputs('Compose')",
                                    "Cheque"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "If"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@triggerBody()",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "get": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

**`Output:`**

**`If Sent Transfer as below:`**

[image]

[image]

**`Output If sent CreditCard:`**

[image]

**`Output If sent Cash:`**

[image]

**`Output If sent Cheque:`**

[image]

Here used **runAfter Failed Succeeded** for conditions(inside conditions used append variable which was initialized empty at first) in design, you can clearly replicate using code( code view) and get to know what the functionality is.